# Facebook AR - Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, augmented-reality

I am using Facebook AR Studio and loosely followed this tutorial to meet my needs : https://blog.tallan.com/2018/04/24/facebook-ar-studio-how-to-use-tap-gestures-to-change-effect-materials/ .

However when I try to play my project, it gives me an error-

JavaScript error: Exception in native code while calling afunction: Child not found: ScreenCanvas 
Backtrace

Here is the code I used.

```
//includes for base libraries
var Scene = require('Scene');
var Tap = require('TouchGestures');
var Mat = require('Materials');

// base dir
var base = 
Scene.root.child('Device').child('Camera').child('Focal 
Distance');
var sCanvas = base.child('ScreenCanvas');
var NoEffectButton  = sCanvas.child('NoEffectButton');
var StageOneButton  = sCanvas.child('StageOneButton');
var effectVisibility = false;

// facemesh

var faceMesh = 
base.child('facetracker0').child('StageOneFaceMesh');


Tap.onTap(NoEffectButton).subscribe(function(event){
                                setEffectVisibility(false);
                                });

Tap.onTap(StageOneButton).subscribe(function(event){
                                faceMesh.material = 
Mat.get('coldsore');
                                setEffectVisibility(true);
                                });

function setEffectVisibility(option){
    if(effectVisibility !== option){
    effectVisibility = option;
    faceMesh.cameraVisibility.forFrontCamera = effectVisibility;
    faceMesh.cameraVisibility.forRearCamera = effectVisibility;
    faceMesh.cameraVisibility.forUnspecifiedCamera = 
effectVisibility;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this just means that you do not have an object in your Scene with the name "ScreenCanvas", as a child of "base". You're probably just targeting something wrong, or have a spelling mistake.

Try using `Diagnostics.log(base)` to make sure you are targeting the correct element. Good luck!